# Java JLabel does not show up

Tags: java, jlabel

`JLabel` isn't showing up! The `buttons()` are only showing when i click in my `frame`. Is it possible to show it without clicking?

```
public frame() {
    frame.setTitle("MyWindowTitle");
    frame.setSize(width, height);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.setResizable(true);
    // frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.add(panel);
    panel.setLocation(150, 150);
    panel.add(new JButton("Hello!"));
    scorel = new JLabel("Score: " + score);
    frame.add(scorel);

    buttons();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make

```
 //frame.pack(); //Dont call pack() if you use null layout
 frame.setVisible(true);
```

is the last statement of your method.
And also use `setSize()` of `panel` as you use `null layout` in `frame`. Without `setSize` and `setLocation` or together `setBounds`, your content does not properly show in `null layout`.

```
panel.setSize(400, 300);
```

also

```
scorel.setSize(width, height);
scorel.setLocation(x, y);
```

**Good Practice**

1. Try to avoid null layout

   To learn about layout please see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html
2. Fix your variable and class name style.
   Learn naming conventions http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html